First order for current expanded in hybridization expansion
I am working with this issue, I want to find the order 1 current for a single impurity Anderson model in the hybridization expansion.The current can be written like
$$I_{\sigma,L}(t)=-2\Im[\text{Tr}(\rho_0\tilde{T}e^{i\int_0^t H_{mix}(s)ds}e^{i(H_{dot}+H_{bath})}\tilde{a}^{\dagger}_{\sigma,L}d_{\sigma}e^{-i(H_{dot}+H_{bath})}Te^{i\int_0^t H_{mix}(s)ds})]$$
where $d$ are the operators acting on the impurity, $a$ the ones acting on the (non interacting) bath, $H_{mix}$ is the tunneling part of the Anderson model, and $H_{dot} = \sum_{\sigma}\varepsilon_d d^{\dagger}d + Un_{\uparrow}n_{\downarrow}$ and H for the bath is a non interacting hamiltonian.
The take now is, when expanding in $H_{mix}$ the operators of the impurity and the ones of the bath are decoupled, so it is possible to collect all the bath contribution and all the impurity contribution separated.
Any hint on this calculation? Or any other idea? Thank you so much
